# alsa-utils-1.0.9 cross compilation for arm issue

Tags: alsa

Hi I am trying to cross compile alsa-utils-1.0.9 using following steps

```
1.tar -xvf alsa-utils-1.0.9.tar.gz
2.cd alsa-utils-1.0.9
3.CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/home/pankaj/3rd/alsa/install/
```

but it shows following error:

```
.
.
.
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux
checking for ld used by GCC... /home/pankil/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/home/pankil/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
**checking for shared library run path origin... /bin/sh: ./config.rpath: No such file or directory**
done
checking whether NLS is requested... no
checking for ALSA CFLAGS...  -I/home/m/3rd/alsa/install/include
checking for ALSA LDFLAGS...  -L/home/m/3rd/alsa/install/lib -lasound -lm -ldl -lpthread
**checking for libasound headers version >= 1.0.9... not present.**
**configure: error: Sufficiently new version of libasound not found.**
```

I have already libasound.so.2.0.0 installed

Comment: The `prefix` option specifies the path on the *target*.

Comment: I also remove prefix tag but still error is same.